# Mono and Linq Aggregate method. Error trying to add items to a new list

Tags: c#, linq, list, mono, accumulate

Why this code doesn't work?

```
public static IList<float> CreateModifiedList(IList<float> list)
{
    IList<float> modifiedList= list.Aggregate(new List<float> (), (l, item) =>l.Add(++item));

    return modifiedList;
}
```

When I try to compile it using Mono I get the following error:

> error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `void' to`
>   System.Collections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work, because `l.Add(++item)` is not returning your aggregate (list of float) - it returns `void`. Second argument should be of type `Func<List<float>, float, List<float>>`. Change your code to return aggregation variable:

`(l, item) => { l.Add(++item); return l; }`

*BTW* What you are doing could be achieved this way:

```
IList<float> modifiedList = list.Select(item => ++item).ToList();
```

Comment: thanks for the correct explanation and moreover the Select method.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
l.Add(++item)
```

to

```
{ l.Add(++item); return l; }
```

As you need to return a list out the back of the aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

Per the signature of [`IEnumerable.Aggregate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548651.aspx), the second parameter should be a `Func<TSource, TSource, TSource>` - in your case, `(float, float) => float`. But [`List.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is a `void` function, and does not return a `float`. Hence the compilation error.